# Extracting data from Facebook login app with Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am starting a new Flutter project the uses Firebase and Facebook for authentication. I actually new to social media signing as I used to develop only the Email and Password method. I created the Facebook app auth successfully and I return the uid of the logged-in user my questions is, how I could use the data gathered from each user like name, profile picture, gender, etc. and where are these data stored, are they stored in Firebase?  I just want to know where to start on this.

Answer (score 0):

Start out by looking at the [flutter_facebook_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth/example) package. In the example tab, it gives you information on how to obtain additional info when logging in through facebook. Namely:

```
final result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions:['email','user_birthday']);
```

Then you can simply retrieve the user data, assign it and use it however you would like.